# How to create Facebook button or box without associating it with my FB applications

Tags: facebook

Often I receive requests from my clients to create FB Like/Fan boxes for their website but I do not want to associate these widgets with my FB apps. Is there a way to create these widgets without associating them with my FB account or using my clients login credentials?